# Work $U$ required to assemble a charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, work, potential-energy, voltage

I'm reading Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism (p. 72) and it gives an relation between the work $U$ required to assemble a charge distribution $ \rho (x,y,z) $ and potential $\phi (x,y,z) $ of that distribution:

$$U=\frac{1}{2}\int \rho \phi dV$$
It proceeds to give an equation representing the energy of a system of discrete point charges:

$$U=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{N}q_{j}\sum_{k\neq j}^{}\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon _{0}}\frac{q_k}{r_{jk}}$$

Can someone explain these equations in a bit more detail and perhaps apply them to a simple problem to illustrate their meaning? I'm a bit confused by the first.

Comment: Comment to notation: Usually $U$ denotes potential energy while $W$ denotes work.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes you're right. For some reason this book phrased it as U. It's not the first time it's had something written incorrectly. Are these equations the potential energy of the arrangement?

Comment: The work you do is stored as potential energy so here $W=U$